# How can I use a number input to make an array?

Tags: php, html

edit: Somebody in the answers recommended a list, and I think that that is a good idea, but then I have no idea of how to implement that with the amount as well as the type. So if someone could explain that?

I have to make a fast food order form for school, and I decided to make you able to enter the amount as an input instead of checkboxes, but I still want them stored in an array. Is there any way to do that? Here's a little snippet of what I have in html:

```html
<form>
  <table class="menu" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td class="productlist">
        <!-- Drinks -->
        <input type="number" name="drinks[]" value="cokeclassic" id="cokeclassic" class="productCheckBox" min="0" max="20" placeholder="0">
        <label for="cokeclassic" class="product">Coca Cola Classic $0.75<br><br></label>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Cart" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to fix your HTML too

Answer (score 0):

If you want them stored in an array, you would need to have multiple input fields with `name="drinks[]"`. All of your inputs will be sent as one array called `drinks`, containing numbers passed in each field.

If you want to pass name of a drink and an amount of it, you would need something like `name="drinks[0].name"` for name of your drink and `name="drinks[0].amount"` for amount

Comment: I'll try to implement it that way. Hopefully it works! But thank you either way.

Answer (score -1):

Why you would like to store them in an array?

When submitting the form, the **input-tag** can only deliver a single value anyways, because there is only a single input.

Try to do a list/stack with the orders or even try to create a dynamic multiselect including amounts when ordering.